# React redux hook useDispatch function how can I call something after it finish

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

In the code that I used to the example I have a property form to add a new property, after it save it in the database I want to update the redux store with the new property and send user to the properties page where all properties are listed but I want to do that after dispatch(addProperty(savedProperty)) then I can do history.push("/properties"). How can I wait there until dispatch finish. I am using useDispatch from react-redux.

```
 async function handlePropertyFormSubmit(values) {
    const savedProperty = await savePropertyGraphQlPromise(values);
    if (savedProperty) {
      dispatch(reset("property"));//reset property form
      dispatch(addProperty(savedProperty));
      //here I want to wait the dispatch finish and then send user to the properties page.
      history.push("/properties");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using async/await so you should be able to use that to await the dispatch as well.

```
 async function handlePropertyFormSubmit(values) {
    const savedProperty = await savePropertyGraphQlPromise(values);
    if (savedProperty) {
      await dispatch(reset("property"));//reset property form
      await dispatch(addProperty(savedProperty));

      history.push("/properties");
    }
  }
```

If the `addProperty` action returns a promise (such as a thunk), you could use the `then` method as well.

```
dispatch(addProperty(savedProperty)).then(() => {
 history.push('/properties')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap you second dispatch with setTimeout
something like this
firstDispatch()
setTimeout(secondDispatch)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'signal' with your dispatch - like `dispatched: false` and set it to true when you finish your `dispatch` (then unset it after redirected, if you intend to use this property in more components). If you're using react router, you can instead render `<Redirect to="yourNewURL" />` to redirect (render it conditionally based on `redux store state`).